# How do I know if part is compatible between manufacturers?

Tags: components, shift-register

I found a schematic that uses the Arduino platform.  It uses shift register part number [7HC595](http://www.nxp.com/products/discretes-and-logic/logic/hct/8-bit-serial-in-serial-or-parallel-out-shift-register-with-output-latches-3-state-based-on-pip-74hc-hct595:74HC_T_595).  I can buy a shift register locally, but it is a [NTE74HC165](http://www.mcmelectronics.com/content/ProductData/Spec%20Sheets/NTE74HC165.pdf).

How do I know if parts are interchangeable?

Comment: Read the data sheets.

Comment: And read so-called "cross-reference" lists

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For these types of chips the numerical suffix (595 and 165) is the function. 595 is an *output* shift register, 165 is an *input* shift register. Definitely *not* interchangeable.

The HC part is the logic family, the technique used in the chip. Both candidates are the same, and HCT would probably work too.

What comes before the 74 is manufacturer-specific, and can mostly be ignored.

To summarize: your chips are not interchangeable.

Comment: Yes, the part number is critical for matching the functional scheme.  However, depending on how the part is used the family/technology lettering may be important as well - speed, signal voltages relative to power, and output drive strength can matter.  The `595 is often used as an I/O expander in Arduino projects, where speed would not be much of a concern but drive strength could be if it is directly feeding LEDs for example.

Comment: Of course Chris, but that wasn't the question here. Both chips he mentions are HC.

Answer (score 2):

If the original designer only specified 74HC595 (no manufacturer called out) then any one should do as well as another*, including an NTE 74HC595. If he or she specified 7HC595 then probably it won't but I suspect that of being a typo.

The professional answer (if you are a designer) is to read the datasheets as @Andy commented, but I am not sure that is all that helpful to you if you are not the designer and are simply trying to duplicate something you found out in the wild.

NTE is not really a manufacturer, they are more a supplier of spare parts for fixit people. Suggest you find parts from a real maker such as TI, Fairchild, NXP, etc. that has full datasheets.

Edit: Wouter (+1) picked up that the critical part of the part number is different. A 74HC595 is **not** the same as a 74HC165- they are completely different.

---

Parts of the part # in front of the 74 normally indicate the manufacturer and have little meaning (not zero, but usually not all that significant). The part after the '595' such as N normally indicates the package type, and it may be different for different manufacturers selling similar package types. 'N' is often a plastic DIP package. Obviously it would be a huge mistake to ignore that if you needed a DIP to fit your PCB or breadboard and ended up with a microscopic chip scale BGA package. Sometimes characters in the suffix portion indicate revisions or variants and are important- you have to read the datasheet to figure it out.

In all cases, I recommend finding and reading the datasheet as the final step, but the guidelines can give you some idea of which datasheets to look at.

* Of course there are so many bad designs out there there is no guarantee that it will work anyway.

Comment: What if it has an "N" on the end of it?

Comment: See my edit above. The suffix + manufacturer normally indicates (at least) the package type. A part may be electrically compatible but the package may be radically different.